# How to prevent text from shifting around as user enters password?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, passwords, uitextfield

Working on an iOS project (iOS 9.1), using standard system San Francisco font.

In my password entry UITextField, the text vertically shifts around as characters turn into the bullet/dot mask things.

Because the dots are smaller then normal characters, something changes with the vertical alignment, making for a jittery experience.

[image]

Can this be avoided?

I've tried changing alignment settings on the UITextField, and alignment settings on the UITextField's parent stackview.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show an image for this?

Comment: added an image. looks like this is what you see with the password fields in apple's apps also, so maybe there is nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: I filed a radar on this 27569477

Comment: @sarhdan commented (as an answer): *"I filed a radar on this 27569477"*

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing font size and/or increasing the height of the UITextField.

Comment: gave this a shot, no luck.